# Xcode upload to notary service fails

Tags: xcode, developer-program

I get this error when I try to upload my app to the notary service. Signing seems to work but not the upload phase.

[image: Xcode error message]

I have tried to close the app and also reboot the computer. The problem persists.

Text: Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.
OS: Mac Monterey (M1)
XCode version: 14.2

I had this working before, but now it's failing. Can I fix this without contacting Apple?

Answer (score 0):

This keeps popping up with many versions of Xcode, and seems to frustrate a lot of people.

["Couldn't communicate with a helper application"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64348054/16157878)

[Xcode 14 build successful, but getting "Could not communicate with a helper application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73443626/cant-sign-into-xcode-couldn-t-communicate-with-a-helper-application)

I had it myself 2-3 times. It seems there are many reasons that could cause this, and there are many suggestions to solve.

Among them:

- Restart your Mac
- Reinstalling Xcode
- Upgrade or downgrade Xcode (upgrade helped me once)
- Upgrading from the OS beta to release version
- Delete the Developer directories
- Check if you have any updated agreement in you Apple Developer account (this helped me once)

There's also a more recent thread on this in [Apple Developer](https://https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725865)